# Apache Jena SDB Transactions support

Tags: java, sql, transactions, jena

I am using Apache Jena Api over SQL database(micrtosoft sql server) known AS JENA SDB
I have problem when i want to acces the database in trensactional manner.
When i use Jena TDB transactions are supported but when i use JENA TDB in stransactinal manner 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Transactions not supported
exception i thrown.

Snippet from Jena TDB which is working is as follows:

```
Dataset dataset =  return TDBFactory.createDataset("datasetLocation");
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
//...
```

Snippet from Jena SDB which is not working is as follows:

```
   StoreDesc storeDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash, 
   DatabaseType.SQLServer);
   SDBConnection sdbConn = new SDBConnection(getConnection());
   Store store = StoreFactory.create(storeDesc, sdbConn);
   Dataset dataset =DatasetStore.create(store);
   dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
   //...this throws the exception
```

My question is since my requirement was to migrate from TDB to SDB(i know it is not recomended)
is there any way to use Jena SDB in transactional manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always transactional - by default, it is autocommit which can be very expensive.

You can manipulate the JDBC connection setting directly, or use any Model's `TransactionHandler` because all the models for the same dataset map to the same code to act on the JDBC connection, which is also available as:

`Store.getConnection().getTransactionHandler()`

Comment: So your solution is to perform commit/rollback directly on jdbc connection like:
    store.getConnection().getSqlConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
    store.getConnection().getSqlConnection().commit();
or using transaction handler,please confirm this.

My idea was to use
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE); 
    dataset.commit(); 
since Dataset is common interface for TDB ans SDB and that way i can use both dependeing on the needs.
Seemes like DatasetGraphSDB which is Dataset implementation in SDB does not support transactions.

Comment: Correct -- SDB does not support Dataset transactions (it predates them).

Comment: Than you for your answer.My last doubt is should i use Jena read/write locking mechanism like model.enterCriticalSection  when using jdbc transactions in SDB (like shown in previous comment) or JDBC transactioin isolation level is enough to solve readers/writers problem.

Comment: You need to lock as well because the JDBC connection is shared across threads in the same JVM.

Comment: In my case it is not shared, I instantiate new JDBC connection from connection pooler on each request and then instantiate SDB store using that connection.